# Design Header meta on single posts wordpress

Tags: headers, custom-header

I want design my header_meta on single posts like this, please help me
[image]

Thank you,

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Could you provide more details, please? Are you developing a custom theme? Or trying to edit some existing theme? Do you need help getting the date and the author? Or just with the styling (color, font, etc.)?

Comment: Hello Antti Koskinen,
I'm trying to edit some existing theme. I just need guide getting the date and the author as example image.
And maybe need some CSS code to styling better
Thank you